# How to handle binding inner data of the view models' properties?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, mvvm-light

Assuming I have a view model like this:

```
public class AddItemViewModel : BaseViewModel //MVVMLight
 {
    ImageData _image1;
    public ImageData Image1
    {
        get { return _image1; }
        set { Set(ref _image1, value); }
    }
 }
```

And `ImageData` has a property `IsDefault` that I need to be bound (two way binding) to the `IsChecked` property of a checkbox control.. what's is the MVVM solution to this? does the `ImageData` model need to be converted to view model by inheriting from `BaseViewModel`?

Currently I'm adding a new property to handle this in the `AddItemViewModel`, for all the 4 images:

```
    private bool _isDefault;
    public bool IsDefault
    {
        get { return _isDefault; }
        set { Set(ref _isDefault, value); }
    }
```

but this looks clumsy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution is to create a view model for ImageData (`ImageDataViewModel`) and put your `IsDefault` property in there:

```
public class ImageDataViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public EventHandler<bool> OnChanging;

    public ImageData Data { get; private set; }

    public ImageDataViewModel(ImageData data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    private bool _isDefault;
    public bool IsDefault
    {
        get { return _isDefault; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._isDefault)
                OnChanging?.Invoke(this, value);
            Set(ref _isDefault, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And then when the parent view model creates these child view models it subscribes to the `OnChanging` event so that it can disable the checkboxes on all the sender's siblings.